# treating of asynchronous executor shutdown when waiting on future

Tags: java, multithreading, asynchronous, executor

I have an ssh client library implementation. Each connection has few executors. One is the thread pool using ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, that is used to queue short lived tasks and timers. One is the read executor, used to hold a packet receiver task. One is the write executor, serially executing tasks, of which each sends one packet to the server. Of course both read and write executor are single threaded, and write executor is used as something like a message queue.

The problem that i have is: methods to queue a message, and some methods queuing tasks, return a CompletableFuture. I queue stuff with CompletableFuture.runAsync method. However, the connection may be asynchronously closed in an orderly or forced manner. In that case some or all pools are shutdown using the shutdownNow method.

What to do in the case that some threads, including threads outside of those pools, could wait for some task to complete synchronously, and there is a risk of asynchronous shutdownNow due to everything including network errors? shutdownNow does not issue future's cancel method. I do not care if actual tasks are interrupted or not, i just care that futures will block indefinitely if executor was shutdown while their task was still in the queue.

What is the best practice to handle this situation? What do people do/etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i believe I have an idea. it is the following:

Because parallel shutdown waits for all tasks to complete, and shutdownNow will just trash them without cancelling, and because I actually end up using completable futures all the time, I decided to maintain a set of completable futures of all kinds per connection, that would hold all tasks including message senders and normal tasks submitted to the task pool. Each method that closes the connection or begins orderly disconnect or so will go through the set and complete all futures exceptionally with some exception. That gives better errors than cancellation. Also nothing should happen if the task will cancel itself this way.

Instead of using runAsync, or normally creating a completable future in case of tasks not associated to runnables, I have a special method that creates such a task, adds it to the set, and attaches a function using CompletableFuture.whenCompleted(), that removes the task from the set if it completed for any reason. I also have runAsync that creates the task using the previously described method, and then submits a runnable using CompletableFuture.completeAsync.

That way all waiting threads should unblock on connection close and get a nice exception from all tasks including sent messages, no matter which method I would use to wait for completion, get() or join().